# What is the purpose of the Adapted Response?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

I am trying to understand the purpose of the Adapted Response from the [doc](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html#adapted-response).

I can not see the purpose of it, could someone provide a very simple example?

Answer (score 1):

It is generally used for another actor to be able to reply to you without knowning anything about you. This occurs any time you have a service actor that can be queried by other actors.

Let's say you put your `User` lookup logic in a central actor that can be queried by sending a message that includes a `replyTo` `ActorRef` such that:

```
object UserBehavior {
  sealed trait UserCommand

  final case class GetUser(userId: Long, replyTo: ActorRef[UserResponse]
    extends UserCommand

  final case class UserResponse(user: User)
}
```

Since we don't have union types in scala *(yet)*, there is no way for all your actors to include `UserResponse` in their behavior without explicitly extending `UserResponse` with every possible receiving behavior.

You create your Behavior with a message that receives a `User` like this:

```
object MyBehavior {

  sealed trait Command

  final case class MyUserResponse(user: User) extends Command
}
```

But how do you create an `ActorRef` that receives a `UserResponse` but arrives at your door looking like a `MyUserResponse`?

You create an adapted response and use it in the construction of your `GetUser` query:

```
userActor ! UserBehavior.GetUser(
  1234,
  context.messageAdapter(x => MyUserResponse(x.user)
```

And now you can receive `MyUserResponse`, since it's part of your behavior.

Comment: Could you please provide a running example?